# adding touchesBegan in multiple classes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

is it possible to have the touchesBegan method in multiple locations or objects in a project?

for example if I have a main class with two buttons:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
 let moveButton = MoveButton()
 let fireButton = FireButton()
 //add buttons to scene etc...
}

class MoveButton: SKSpriteNode {
 override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
  NSLog("moved!")
 }
}

class FireButton: SKSpriteNode {
 override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
  NSLog("fired!")
 }
}
```

currently I have something similar but the touchesBegan aren't being hit, is this incorrect to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be perfectly fine to implement `touchesBegan` in several places. Regarding why they aren't called, perhaps this can help? [Custom SKSpriteNode not detected during touch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19484396/1091402)